# Fazer pergunta hipotética sobre uma situação não codificada

Tags: debate, perguntas, escopo-do-site

Um usuário fez [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92652/como-criar-lista-de-presen%C3%A7as) a respeito de lista de presença em PHP. Apesar de ter sido marcada como pendente eu acabei ficando curioso sobre uma aplicação disso em modelagem de dados, mas eu não estou desenvolvendo nada a respeito, apenas uma curiosidade.

Diante disto lhes pergunto: fazer uma pergunta sobre uma situação hipotética apenas para esclarecer uma dúvida particular é considerada uma pergunta ruim? Questiono isso porque sempre leio perguntas de outras pessoas e me vem alguma dúvida hipotética a respeito daquele problema em outra situação, mas fico receoso em perguntar por se tratar de uma situação que eu (pelo menos naquele momento) não vou implementar em lugar algum, apenas para adquirir conhecimento mesmo.

Comment: Acho que a pergunta é má quando a pessoa pergunta sem esforço e mostra intenção de que alguém entenda a pergunta e responda com um código feito. Se a pergunta perguntar por estrutura ou lógica de programação a coisa fica bem mais interessante. Aí o perigo é não cair na pergunta que pede respostas baseadas em opiniões. O que quero dizer é que por vezes pode ser muito interessante e suficiente ter uma resposta com uma explicação da solução sem código.

Comment: @Sergio seria o ideal. De qualquer forma vou tentar brincar com essa minha dúvida aqui no programa de modelagem, assim terei mais embasamento pra formular a minha dúvida.

Comment: A meu ver, utilizar uma dúvida, por mas que seja hipotética, não gera problemas. O problema está em como apresentar essa informação em forma de pergunta. Se você conseguir fazer isso, não vejo problemas em perguntar.

Comment: O problema é quando é feita uma pergunta nessa estrutura, "Olá, bom dia, tudo bem? espero que sim. Então galera quero criar uma rede social mas não tenho nehuma ideia por onde começar." As perguntas devem ter um problema especifico, elas não são brainstorms.

Answer (score 7):

O problema da pergunta hipotética é que a pessoa costuma não ter noção do que ele vai perguntar. Não é que ele não entende do assunto. Como ele não tem um problema real, ele não consegue montar a pergunta em uma forma que dê para responder.

Mas se ele conseguir, não tem problema algum.

Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Não há nada claro sobre isto, nem que pode e nem que não pode. Então minha interpretação é que é algo possível, faz parte do nosso foco. Mas deve-se tomar cuidado para não cair aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Se conseguir evitar que a pergunta seja puramente opinativa, não seja muito ampla, ou seja, dá uma descrição geral e quem for responder ter que fazer especulações, pensar em todos os aspectos possíveis, e tenha clareza, tenha um problema bem definido, no que está sendo perguntado, não tem porque não fazer.

Acho que em casos assim o autor deve pensar bastante antes de postar e ficar atento aos comentários para melhorar o que for sendo criticado. Pense bem no problema antes de perguntar. Se coloque no lugar de quem vai ler a pergunta e responder. Você tem que se comunicar corretamente com ele.

Com boa vontade, sabendo escrever, tudo que for de programação pode ser perguntado. O que não pode é a pessoa "vomitar" a pergunta e esperar que os outros se virem para responder. Faça o seu "dever de casa" e terá respostas. Abuse da boa vontade alheia e terá um fechamento.

Você já deu o primeiro passo que é se preocupar em fazer o certo, ouvir o que os outros têm a dizer sobre algo que pode ser polêmico.

Torço para fazer uma boa pergunta e conseguir o que deseja.

Comment: Eis o caso que muita gente acaba pecando, que é fazer uma pergunta pedindo mais opinioes e as vezes nem se da conta de que fez. Agradeço pelas dicas, acabei fazendo uns testes aqui e lendo uns casos parecidos pesquisados aqui, acabei achando soluções pra dúvida de modelagem. O legal deste site é que ele acaba te ajudando com sugestões bem relevantes, antes de você clicar  no botão "Fazer uma pergunta".

Answer (score 2):

Também pode seguir a pista da pergunta que levantou sua curiosidade e ver o que já foi perguntado antes à respeito.

Nessa pergunta que usa como exemplo, tem uma lista de perguntas *Relacionadas* à direita:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Pode também fazer uma pesquisa usando as tags da pergunta mais a palavra-chave: `[php] [mysql] modelagem`, que [produz 16 resultados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20%5Bmysql%5D%20modelagem). E, [a mesma pesquisa](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20%5Bmysql%5D%20modeling) no Stack Overflow em inglês.

Creio que navegando nessas perguntas e respostas pode achar algum exemplo interessante de código ou teoria para implementar, e a partir daí provavelmente já terá alguma dúvida prática para fazer uma boa pergunta aqui no site.

Comment: A medida em que se digita a pergunta, surgem umas já criadas, já pesqusei o caso e encontrei perguntas bem parecidas, essa ferramenta é realmente muito boa, é dificil perguntar algo que ja se tenha perguntado, a nao ser por desatenção na hora de criar a pergunta.

Comment: Exato, essa é uma forma de pesquisar também. Não precisa publicar a pergunta, só de ir digitando sua dúvida já vai sugerindo material semelhante.